# How can i keep image sizes, defined by x\textwidth, after change of the textwidth?

Tags: graphics, lengths

i set up all image sizes by `x\textwidth`. Unfortunately i have to turn in the paper with another textwidth. Is there a possibility to keep the image sizes exactly like they are right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly with a bit of manual work. You can find out what `\textwidth` corresponds to using `\the\textwidth`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\the\textwidth
\end{document}
```

or by using the `layout` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

After finding the length, you just need to calculate the corresponding lengths for `X\textwidth`, and replace those with the explicit length.

Alternatively, you could create a new length that holds the old textwidth, and use that instead, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\oldtextwidth
\setlength\oldtextwidth{345pt} % get this value from examples above
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\oldtextwidth]{example-image} % use \oldtextwidth instead of \textwidth
\end{document}
```